# Как поменять картинку (иконку) при запуске приложения (SplashScreen)

Tags: android, android-themes, splash-screen

У меня есть стили

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:startColor="#158ED7"
                android:endColor="#66E2FC"
                android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Указал путь на нужную картинку

```
<resources>
    
    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/gradient_background</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

Я вот так вот сделал и применил эту тему к MainActivity в манифесте. Но при запуске задний фон меняется на просто голубой цвёт (градиент почему то не применился), и картинка не меняется, показывается иконка приложения. Проверял на своём телефоне на Андроид 12.

Потом проверил на эмуляторе Андроид 7, там это работает: градиент показывается как надо и картинка тоже.

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, на какой версии Андроид вы проверяете работу этого кода.

Comment: Изначально проверил на Андроид 12 – не работает, сейчас проверил на Андроид 7 – там всё работает.

Comment: Чтобы реализовать [Splash Screen на Андроид 12](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen), нужно использовать атрибуты `windowSplashScreenBackground` и `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon`. В первом атрибуте задайте drawable для вашего фона, а во втором задайте drawable для изображения, которое будет в центре экрана.

Comment: *"проверил на Андроид 7 – там всё работает"* -- я в это не верю, селектор, который вы написали в вопросе, является некорректным, второй `item` будет проигнорирован.

Comment: Но у меня всё работает, нормально отображается второй `item`, вместо иконки приложения, отображается 
то изображение, которое я указал

Answer (score 0):

В Андроид `selector` работает таким образом, что выбирается первый `item`, который подходит по условию. В ваших `item` нет условий, поэтому всегда будет выбираться первый `item`, а второй `item` будет игнорироваться.

Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, вам необходимо использовать [`layer-list`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList), а не [`selector`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList). Это позволит наложить один `item` поверх другого:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient ... />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap ... />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Кроме этого, чтобы реализовать [Splash Screen для Android 12 и выше](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen), нужно использовать атрибуты `windowSplashScreenBackground` и `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Что то не работает :(

Comment: Я добавил пояснение в ответ, мой ответ исправляет ошибку в вашем drawable. Возможно, у вас есть какая-то другая ошибка, приведите детали и приложите текст ошибки в [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Либо вы проверяете на Android 12, там нужно делать по-другому, об этом указано в моем ответе.